# Spring @Autowired repository not working in @Override Netty method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, netty

I was developing a Netty Socket project with Spring Data but I'm definitely can't use Spring's repository class in `@Override` method. It works in any method other than the `@Override` method, I tried calling it with `@PostConstruct`.

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CassandraRepository<Account, UUID> {}
```

```
@Service
public class WebSocketHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    public static List<String> requiredData = Arrays.asList(
            "request_type"
    );

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if(!(msg instanceof TextWebSocketFrame)) return;
        
        System.out.println(accountRepository);//problems there, accountRepository always return null;

        JSONObject data;
        try {
            data = new JSONObject(((TextWebSocketFrame) msg).text());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return;
        }

        for(String required : requiredData) {
            try {
                data.get(required);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return;
            }
        }

        RequestModule requestModule = RequestAdapter.getModule(data.get("request_type").toString());
        if(requestModule == null) return;

        requestModule.onAction(ctx, data);
    }
}
```

```
public class Netty {
    private UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor executorGroup;

    public Netty() {
        UtilConsole.log("Netty sunucusu aktifleşiyor...");
        try {
            enable();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void enable() throws Exception {
        ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel( ResourceLeakDetector.Level.DISABLED ); // Eats performance

        EventLoopGroup producer = new NioEventLoopGroup(32);
        EventLoopGroup consumer = new NioEventLoopGroup(32);

        try{
            executorGroup = new UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor(32);

            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
                    .group(producer, consumer)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

                            pipeline.addLast("httpServerCodec", new HttpServerCodec());
                            pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Short.MAX_VALUE));

                            pipeline.addLast(executorGroup, "httpHandler", new NettyListener());
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 100000)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            UtilConsole.log("Netty sunucusu aktif edildi!");
            bootstrap.bind(Configuration.NETTY_PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            UtilConsole.log("Netty sunucusu aktif edilemedi.");
            throw ex;
        }finally{
            producer.shutdownGracefully();
            consumer.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class NettyListener extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private WebSocketServerHandshaker handshaker;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
        if(msg instanceof HttpRequest){
            HttpRequest httpRequest = (HttpRequest) msg;

            HttpHeaders headers = httpRequest.headers();

            if("Upgrade".equalsIgnoreCase(headers.get(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION)) && "WebSocket".equalsIgnoreCase(headers.get(HttpHeaderNames.UPGRADE))){
                ctx.pipeline().replace(this, "websocketHandler", new WebSocketHandler());
                handleHandshake(ctx, httpRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

This definitely doesn't work and `accountRepository` always returning `null`.

I want to be able to use a `@Autowired` variable in the `@Override channelRead` method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's better to add also how you use your WebSocketHandler with netty

Comment: Sure, let i edit question.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can do autowire, and all other "magic stuff", IF and only if it's spring itself that build the instance of the class.

The problem is in your `NettyListener` class where *you* build the instance with `new WebSocketHandler()`. In this way, Spring doesn't know anything about that, and can't initialize it properly.

My advice is to build your netty configuration passing the WebSocketHandler instance returned by spring in this way:

```
@Configuration
public MyAppConfiguration {

  @Autowire
  WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler

  @PostConstruct
  public void configureNetty() {
    //...netty-things I don't know...
    //netty.useHandler(webSocketHandler)
  }

}
```

OT: I saw `UtilConsole.log()` and as a general advice, never reinvent the wheel, and logging frameworks are more complex than they appears. A look to 'logback' (the most beloved by spring-framework) could help you.

Comment: by `@PostConstruct`, do you mean `@Bean`?

Comment: @TNYCL no I mean `@PostConstruct`. Classes annotated with `@Configuration` are always managed/istantiated by spring, so using `@PostConstruct` you can do something after construction knowing that all autowired beans will be in place. Another (more OOP) way is to provide a constructor where you receive the WebSocketHandler instance as argument of the coonstructor and then you can initialize netty with that instance --- see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-constructor-injection